# Remove an '?' char from tqdm progressbar?

Tags: python, cmd, request, progress-bar, tqdm

I wrote a code that download videos with progressbar using `tqdm` module, and it works fine, just there is a '?' char appeared in the progressbar and it only appears in the cmd.

here is a pic of the
[progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ6ss.png)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are working under Windows the cmd has some problems showing utf8 characters. Try `ascii=True` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's written in the [FAQ and Known Issues](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues) of tqdm or [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/454#issuecomment-335416815) that windows has some problems with unicode characters. Use the parameter `ascii=True` to fix this problem.

```py
from time import sleep
from tqdm import trange

for i in trange(100, ascii=True):
    sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `ascii=True` gave me an output like ###5. But `ascii=' █'` solved the questionark issue.